# Centrino N-6205 frequent disconnection

Tags: networking

I have frequent disconnections from internet using wifi. It happens only when I'm on my home network and it doesn't happens on other devices that are connected to my router. So it seems specific to this computer with this network. Here some info about my setup.

- Laptop: Lenovo X230
- wireless card : Centrino advance N-6205
- Ubuntu 12.04 64bits
- Kernel: 3.5.0-23-generic
- Network encryption: WPA

When it happens, the network manager applet shows that I'm connected but it's impossible to open an internet page. I have to reconnect to the network to have internet back.

Thanks for helping, much appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a pretty old router and it seems it was the problem. I changed it and now everything works fine. Old router vs brand new laptop wasn't quite compatible.

Answer (score 0):

After many variants of the [iwlwifi-opt.conf and related fixes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675352/wireless-disconnects-intermittently-with-intel-corporation-centrino-advanced-n-6/675361#675361), my issue was completely resolved by opening the case and re-seating the network card and antenna.

My system is also Lenovo x230 with an Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34) ([x230 manual](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/x230t_ug_en.pdf))