# Wireless Disconnects Intermittently with Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

I am on Ubuntu 15.04 using xfce (xubuntu) and am having trouble with my wi-fi. The indicator continues to show that I am connected to the network but after some amount of time I will no longer have internet access. In order to fix the issue I simply disconnect from the network and reconnect which always resolves it. I have had this issue occur on different networks.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0"
```

and reboot.

In many cases only `11n_disable=8` is sufficient.

---

Explanation:

The [iwlwifi Linux kernel driver](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi) supports several Intel wireless LAN adapters. The command adds the following configuration to the `iwlwifi` module:

```
11n_disable=1      Disables the 802.11n mode
11n_disable=8      Enables agg TX option
swcrypto=1         Disables hardware encryption and uses software instead.
bt_coex_active=0   Disables bluetooth coexistence technology that works poorly with iwlwifi
power_save=0       Disables the power save mode
```

To restart the services without rebooting to test alternative configurations:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwldvm iwlwifi
sudo service network-manager restart
```

The shorthand command additionally uses a [`here string`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) via the `<<<` operator in Bash to append these characters to the configuration file.

Comment: I made this change and restarted but am still having the same issue

Comment: Do you use bluetooth?

Comment: No. There's no bluetooth daemon running from what I can tell

Comment: @user3330797 I updated the command.

Comment: Ok I made the change and rebooted. Had plymouth crash on start up but I'm not sure if that's related

Comment: It is not related, just test the wireless.

Comment: Ok I'm using wifi and will let you know if the internet drops out at any point in the next hour or so.

Comment: Everything is working fine still! Think the updated command might have done it. Thank you

Comment: @user3330797 You can try to remove `11n_disable=1` from the command and test it too. That will not disable the fast `802.11n` mode. Maybe `swcrypto=1 bt_coex_active=0` is enough.

Comment: This is not working at all for me. When I add the text to `iwlwifi-opt.conf` and restart things, I get the following error: `libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:673 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with '11n_disable=1'`

Comment: @Greg Oops. I posted a wrong command. Fixed it. I missed two words.

Comment: `11n_disable=8` is working for me on 20.04. However, reloading the module and restarting Network Manager was not sufficient. Failures continued to occur until I restarted the OS.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a router issue. Despite [the fixes suggested above](https://askubuntu.com/a/675361/1009151), it turns out that my 6205 adapter could not handle an access point that allowed dynamic steering between 2.4/5 Ghz (called *SmartSteering* - specific to my router). There are to viable options to help the 6205 adapter:

### Connection settings (best - stable now for more than 6 months)

Use a GUI to change the settings for the AP, like `nm-connection-editor`. The relevant setting would be changing the Band from *automatic* to a specific Band.

*XOR*

### Router settings (not ideal, but works as well)

I turned off Smart-Steering, allowing the router to broadcast two separate APs, one for 5GHz, another for 2.4GHz (I needed both). Now, I could connect to the 5GHz AP with my laptop with no issues.