# wireless driver

Tags: wireless, thinkpad

I am still a beginner user of Linux (and also of this forum).
I own a Thinkpad T430 and since I switched to ubuntu (15.10) from windows7, I have the feeling that my network interface controller doesn't work as well as with Windows. 
What could it be?

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21f3]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please explain your "feeling" why it works not well?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/675352/wireless-disconnects-intermittently-with-intel-corporation-centrino-advanced-n-6

Comment: I think that when I am connected through Wi-Fi, internet is slower..

Comment: Try to test it by copying some file using wireless network. The driver is OK.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm sorry.. my questions are really silly, but as I said I'm just a beginner..

Comment: Anyway there is no other driver. Everything is installed OK.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much! By the way, can you suggest me some easy introduction to Unix world? For example a book? Where should I start?

Comment: I followed the link that you putted in the comment and I copied and pasted the instruction that I found in the answer in that link in my terminal, but now I can't connect to the WiFi.. (I'm using my smartphone right now..)

Comment: There was no need to do that. You can revert it by `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf` and reboot.

Comment: I think I did a mess.. After running that command, since I saw that wasn't working, I run it again and I changed some 0s with 1s and also some 1s with 0s.. what should I do?

Comment: I'm sorry.. I'm an idiot..

Comment: Just remove the config file with the command I gave in a previous comment and reboot.

Comment: I removed that file but I still can't use Internet..