# Problems with wireless

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

I'm a ubuntu beginner user. 
I thought to have some problems with the driver of my network interface problems but apparently there weren't any ( [wireless driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731341/wireless-driver) ).
Unfortunately I went here: [Wireless Disconnects Intermittently with Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675352/wireless-disconnects-intermittently-with-intel-corporation-centrino-advanced-n-6)

and I decided to open my terminal and digit:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0"
```

Then my computer wasn't able to detect any WiFi connections anymore..

So I tried to digit the previous command again changing some 0s and 1s (I know that it's stupid..) but of course didn't work.
Then I finally removed the file with:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```

but I didn't solve the problem. I can't use internet anymore. I mean, I can, but I have to use an ethernet cable.

EDIT:

The output of `ls /etc/modprobe.d` is the following:

```
alsa-base.conf              blacklist-rare-network.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf      blacklist-watchdog.conf
blacklist.conf              fbdev-blacklist.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf     intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf  iwlwifi.conf
blacklist-modem.conf        mlx4.conf
blacklist-oss.conf          vmwgfx-fbdev.conf
```

EDIT #2: this is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:cc:d2:65:42  
          inet addr:192.168.0.8  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:ccff:fed2:6542/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2013 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1513 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1911969 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:152735 (152.7 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2500000-f2520000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:72478 (72.4 KB)  TX bytes:72478 (72.4 KB)
```

EDIT #3: Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
    00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
```

EDIT #4: Here is the output of `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*`:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:remove iwlwifi \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
```

Comment: Did you reboot? The second command should revert all settings. And post output of `ls /etc/modprobe.d`

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: When I look at that 'ls /etc/modprobe.d' output I see another 'iwlwifi.conf' file. Check the output of that file with 'cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf'. You could also edit that file and disable the 'options'. For that, just edit the file with 'sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf' and put a '#' sign in front of the 'options' line. save with < ctrl > x...

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6 is the 15.10

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I put the output! :)

Comment: I see that the driver is not loaded at all. It is blacklisted somewhere. Run `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`. Does it work after this? And also post output of `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*`.

Comment: Ok so now I'll post the output of  `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*` and then I'll try with `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

Comment: @Pilot6 I put the output! :) Now I'll try with `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`. But what does it mean exactly?

Comment: It should start the `iwlwifi`module.

Comment: Ok I tried but the output is this:

modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Function not implemented

Comment: If you want I can edit my question again and put the output there, so it would be more clear..

Comment: It looks like you broke the kernel module somehow. You will need to re-install the kernel image. I am leaving now.

Comment: So it means that I have to re install my OS? :(

Comment: No just the kernel. Post output of `uname -a; dkms status`.

Comment: I re-installed the kernel and now I can connect with wireless!!! :D

Comment: If you write an answer I can give you the bounty!

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you removed `iwlwifi` module.

You need to re-install the kernel. Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-`uname-r` linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

do

```
$ iwconfig
```

to see your wireless interface name (a typical name is for example **wlan0**)

Then use

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning
```

(replace wlan0 with your wireless interface name)

If you can see a list of connections then it is not a problem of driver and you can try to do

```
$ sudo service network-manager stop
$ sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
$ sudo service network-manager start
```

Use this command too and put all your outputs here

```
$ sudo rfkill list all
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with       `$ iwconfig`
and I got this:
`eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.`

Comment: mmm can you put the {$ ifconfig} output? it seems like your wireless card is not configured or you don't have the wireless card driver installed

Comment: I put the output! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with the driver of your wireless card. First step I would do is delete the line you added:

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```

This will allow you to edit the file, find the line (`"options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0"')and delete or comment it.

I'm not sure how to fix the intermittancy of the driver. I do find that running:

```
sudo iwlist scanning
```

helps my card to detect networks and give it a little jolt.