# Lenovo T440S wireless not enabled in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, lenovo, firmware

recently I upgraded Ubuntu from version 18.xx to 20.xx, with the surprise that wireless and sound are not available.

Below is show the details:

**ID**

```
$ uname -a; dkms status

Linux ac-ThinkPad-T440s 5.4.0-1062-gke #65-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 6 05:12:01 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Network**

```
$ lshw -C network

    *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: 28:d2:44:8b:48:f0
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.6-3 ip=192.168.0.30 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:46 memory:e0600000-e061ffff memory:e063e000-e063efff ioport:3080(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0400000-e0401fff
```

**Conf files**

```
$ sudo ls -l /etc/modprobe.d

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2507 lip 31  2015 alsa-base.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  154 cze 26  2018 amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   26 lut 15 00:34 ath9k.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  325 sty 28  2018 blacklist-ath_pci.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1518 mar 12  2020 blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  210 sty 28  2018 blacklist-firewire.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  677 kwi  9  2020 blacklist-framebuffer.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  156 lip 31  2015 blacklist-modem.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 lis 28  2019 blacklist-oss.conf -> /lib/linux-sound-base/noOSS.modprobe.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  583 sty 28  2018 blacklist-rare-network.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  127 sty 22  2020 dkms.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  154 cze 20  2019 intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  350 lut 15 01:33 iwlwifi.conf
```

**iwlwifi**

```
$ sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
#remove iwlwifi \
#(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
#&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

**NOTE:** The conf file I edited commenting all lines, I read in a blog that might be a solution and at the end with no success.

**Device**

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3


03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c270]
```

I have been reading and following the Ububtu recommendations [according to this Wiki article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Firmware) with no success.

Besides, I have read [this case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731391/problems-with-wireless) which is quite similar to mine and the solution was to reinstall the kernel?

No idea what does it mean, the kerner of ubuntu? the kernel of the device?

May someone of you support me in this case?

**I am just considering to reinstall a previous version of UBUNTU**

Thanks.

..:: =================================================== ::..

Command:

sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware

Results:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-firmware is already the newest version (1.187.26).
linux-firmware set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware` then `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` and then `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo shutdown -r now` and after you log in again type `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'Wirelessl|firm'; rfkill list all` and post the result for us.

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Our T440S is working fine on 20.04 using the hwe kernel

Comment: Hi @pilot6, the command "dmesg | grep iwl" shows no result.

Comment: Hi @OrganicMarble, how did you do that? I mean, install a different kernel?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Hej @darth_epoxy, please take a look to the results of the command "sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware" ; considering the results, I did not proceed with the followings commands. Let me know :)

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel using grub. It looks like kernel is not fully installed.

Comment: Hello guys, just to inform that proposal of downgrade the kernel did not work, neither the recovery mode. Graphics, sound and wireless service were unable to use.
So I decide to re-install Ubuntu 18.04 and everthing is okej now.

Thank you,