# Can't connect x220 to wifi on 16.04.1

Tags: wireless, 16.04

I've checked countless other forums and can't seem to figure it out. On my last laptop, on 14.04, a simple tweak of changing security to peap worked. Now, I don't know what to do. Any advice is great!

-Tried restarting multiple times
-Haven't really ran any code so far
-SSID and WIFI password are correct

//edit after running **$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2**

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:21ce]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

//edit

I looked on the other forum you linked me to, I ran that line of code, rebooted, and wifi still wont work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wireless Disconnects Intermittently with Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 \[Taylor Peak\] \[8086:0085\] (rev 34)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/675352/wireless-disconnects-intermittently-with-intel-corporation-centrino-advanced-n-6)

Comment: okay so what do I do to fix this?