# I'm not able to create wifi hotspot in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

Please Don't mark it as duplicate.
I recently move to Linux from Windows. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my PC. Now I want to create wifi-hotspot in my Ubuntu-18.04 to share internet with my android phone.
I've watched several tutorials and read many articles about But still I'm not able to create wifi-hotspot. Could any please guide me to do that?
I'll be thankful to him/her :)

Comment: Look.. I clicked on ham-burger icon in wifi option of setting -> Turn on wifi hotspot -> Turn on
And nothing happen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot/180734#180734)

Comment: If hotspot doesn't work, check for its driver. your wifi module may not be well-supported.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to check drivers?

Comment: check the output of `lspci -vvnn | grep Network` and `lshw -C network` then find your wifi vendor, check the chipset and driver from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported

Comment: 00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ea] (rev 05)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [103c:7008]
43:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 [8086:4239] (rev 35)

Comment: Your chipset(Intel Advanced-N 6200) is not supported according https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsIntel. this may help you https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274562, or maybe this https://askubuntu.com/questions/675352/wireless-disconnects-intermittently-with-intel-corporation-centrino-advanced-n-6

Comment: @Mohammads His wifi chipset is perfectly well supported by the driver *iwlwifi*, despite the outdated link you gave. The question is whether the driver supports AP mode. Find out with the command: `iw list` Does it show: "Supported interface modes:
   * IBSS
   * managed
   * AP
   * AP/VLAN
   * monitor
   * P2P-client
   * P2P-GO
   * P2P-device"

Comment: @chili555 I got following result:
Supported interface modes:
   * IBSS
   * managed
   * monitor

Comment: I was using wifi-hotspot in same PC on window 7. So, it's not happening here?

Comment: See my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Sure I'm waiting...

Comment: @chili555 Try for using `iwlwifi` wasn't successful, check the forum https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274562.

Comment: @Mohammads That's not a driver issue, it's a router issue. As far as is evident here, the OP connects perfectly well to his router with *iwlwifi* as do I with my Intel device.

Comment: @chili555 Oh, you're right. The STA mode is fine!

Answer (score 2):

After you ran the terminal command:

```
iw list
```

You found:

```
 Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * monitor
```

Not every device supports every mode using Linux drivers. In many cases, perhaps most, there are modes that work perfectly well in Windows or even macOS, that don't work at all in Linux.

**Footnote**: It is perfectly possible, barring a whitelist,  to swap out your device to get other features support as I have. For an example, my device: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 83) reports the following:

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
     * P2P-client
     * P2P-GO
     * P2P-device
```

Comment: So, what would be possible solution for this??

Comment: Get a different device, I am sorry to say.

Comment: Oh! it's annoying me :(